# Use SED to produce a specific format from values in a text file (line by line)

Tags: linux, string, shell, csv, sed

I have a ports.txt file containing the following data "IP Address, local port, remote port and protocol". This is what the file looks like:

```
1.1.1.1-22-2222-tcp
2.2.2.2-3000-4321-udp
3.3.3.3-80-8080-tcp
4.4.4.4-443-4443-tcp
```

What I would like to do is use SED to edit each line by putting the values from the ports.txt file in the correct places.

I've used line 1 from the ports.txt file as an example of the expected outcome:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:22
```

I have worked out that I can read line by line using a loop like this:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < ports.txt
```

but I have no idea how to get SED to extract the values and put them into the required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -rn 's/(^.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*$)/A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p \4 -m \4 --dport \3 -j DNAT --to-destination \1:\2/p' ports.txt
```

Split the lines into individual sections split with - and substitute the lines for the different sections (designated with \n) printed in the format required.

Comment: Note this isn't returning the right port number. Should be `--dport \3`

Comment: Good spot @costaparas I have amended

Comment: You guys all have brains the size of planets! thank you so much for the fast responses :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution below uses `echo`, `sed`, `tail` and `grep` to extract the port, protocol and destination.

**For the destination:** we remove the port & protocol from the end & then substitute the dash (`-`) for a colon (`:`). (Also, as a precaution, trailing whitespace is accounted for).

**For the protocol:** we just remove everything up until the final `-`, and any trailing whitespace just in case.

**For the port:** we use `grep` to find all the numeric sequences, `-o` giving us just the matching component & then we extract the last such match using `tail -1`.

```
: '
INPUT:
1.1.1.1-22-2222-tcp
2.2.2.2-3000-4321-udp
3.3.3.3-80-8080-tcp
4.4.4.4-443-4443-tcp

OUTPUT:
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:22
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 4321 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:3000
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 3.3.3.3:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4443 -j DNAT --to-destination 4.4.4.4:443
'

while read -r line
do
    dest=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/-[^-]*-[^-]*\s*$//;s/-/:/')
    protocol=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*-//;s/\s*$//')
    port=$(echo "$line" | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | tail -1)
    echo "-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p $protocol -m $protocol --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $dest"
done < ports.txt
```

Comment: This answer is also great thankyou very much but I noticed that the protocol is permanently set to tcp.

Comment: Nice catch @confused, it now inserts the protocol as well

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'-' -lane 'my ( $ip_address, $local_port, $remote_port, $protocol ) = @F; print "-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m ${protocol} --dport ${remote_port} -j DNAT --to-destination ${ip_address}:${local_port}";' ports.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'-'` : Split into `@F` on dash (`-`), rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: I didnt think to use perl, many thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, set the field delimiter to - and then print using the fields, in the format required.

```
awk -F- '{ print "A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p "$4" -m "$4" --dport "$3" -j DNAT --to-destination "$1":"$2 }' ports.txt
```